# Public Read and Write ACL despite all permissions being disabled

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class with all the permissions disabled, so it's available only to my cloud code while using the master key. But I looked at it today and I'm seeing that suddenly each of my objects has a Public Read and Write ACL.

What does it mean? I do not want anyone writing to, or reading from this class. Do I have to now set this in two different places?

I should add that this class contains information that I've added myself through the data browser. No app is writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this a bit confusing and here's what I think is happening:

There appears to be the same notion of `undefined` for ACL's as for other cells.  I think that is the default security ACL (non) value.  However, when the ACL is undefined, it gets reported in the Data table viewer, under the ACL column, as "Public Read and Write".  I suspect that someone at Parse decided that showing `(undefined)` for the ACL wouldn't do justice to informing the developers of the security risk of having no ACL for the row.

As evidence of what I'm thinking, I have noticed that when you click on an ACL cell (as if to edit), and it brings up the security dialog box for the ACL of the row, then, in the original cell itself (where you clicked, now in the background), it shows the text (in JSON) of the old ACL, if there is one actually defined, and shows `(undefined)` if there isn't one defined yet.

My observation is that class-specified security overrides what I'm calling the undefined ACL security setting.

IMHO, it would be better in this case if the Data view page showed something more illustrative: instead of "Public Read and Write", for example, "(undefined: see class security...).

Also, it is not yet clear to me how class security combines with row-defined ACLs (i.e. when present).  If I find out one way or the other, I'll update...

(Also, fyi, sometimes it seems to me that you may have to give a few minutes before seeing security setting changes take effect.)

Comment: Thanks @Eric. This makes sense, although I hope someone from Parse.com would come with an official explanation. Also, I hope you're right but I'm not entirely sure that class security overrides object level ACL. Maybe there are exceptions?

Comment: Right. I was only commenting on my personal observation that the class security appears to override an "undefined" row ACL (shown as Public R&W).  Since writing that, additional (very) simple tests of mine seem to indicate that you cannot expose things using row ACL that are restricted by class security; however, obviously someone from Parse.com needs to make a definitive claim about how class security interacts with row ACLs.  My simple tests involved a non logged in request vs. an authorized user; more comprehensive would be to also test multiple other users, which I have not done to date.

Comment: Any query or write operation must first pass CLP (class level permission) before it gets to the object where it then must pass its own ACL. In other words, CLP only adds restriction.